# PPA & Packaging: Packaging Source as a Binary Package

Tags: 10.04, ppa, python, packaging

I'm trying to create a .deb for a python-based IRC bot.  I've already gone through the Ubuntu Packaging Guide, and done a `debuild -S` on it to create the source package.

When its uploaded to the PPA, it fails to include the code for the bot (which is necessary for the bot to run).  How do I make the .deb so that it (a) isnt a source package, and (b) includes the code for the bot so that it can be run?

**Edit**
And by "includes the code for the bot so that it can be run", I mean so that the .deb extracts the code to the location in the virtual file structure that I specified so that it can be used by any user.  Note that because its a python bot, there's no single executable file in the code, which explains the need for the source to be packaged and extracted with the .deb

Comment: Oh, and to answer your first question, just run `debuild` without `-s` to build a binary package.

Comment: Regarding that, i did that before, and the PPA system wouldnt accept it :/

Comment: @Evil: You can only upload source files.

Comment: @George: Will the files subsequently be built on the PPA so that they install (i.e. end up as the binary .deb)?

Comment: @Evil: Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: @George: so the final step is to include/create the <packagename>.install file which will explain what from the source should be copied to the system, and specifically, where each individual source file should go?

Comment: @Evil: Yup. That's exactly what the `.install` file does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, assuming your package is named `ircbot`, create a file named `ircbot.install` in the `debian` folder. This file contains instructions for the installer to copy certain files to their destination in the virtual filesystem you are referring to.

From there, it's simply a matter of adding the names of the files you want copied.

So, if you have a file `bot.py` that goes to `/usr/share/ircbot/bot.py`, you would add a line to `ircbot.install` like so:

```
bot.py usr/share/ircbot
```

Comment: I've gotta have a "Stalker Alert" for ya dude, you answer most of my questions :P

On another note, given that the bot is modular, and requires about 18 other python files to operate (and its all stored in multiple folders), is there a way I can specify "Copy all from the folder here TO /usr/share/ircbot/" ?

Comment: @Evil: I'm sure there is... but I don't know what it is :P

Comment: Well this should work.  Lets hope that it operates right (and copies files where they belong) with the PPA after its all built ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create an "install" file in the "debian" folder, like this:

```
local_file /system/path/where/to/copy/file
local_file2 /system/path/where/to/copy/file2
.... add as many files/folders as you want
```

Then, installing the .deb will only move the files to the right folders.